# De consulta SQL a Consulta en Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Tengo la siguiente consulta en `SQL` que funciona bien

```
SELECT MONTH(NOW()) AS mes, SUM(importe) as monto FROM pago_cliente WHERE MONTH(fecha_del_deposito) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(fecha_del_deposito) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY 1
```

Y busco trasformarla de tal forma para que sea una consulta exitosa en PHP, uso codeigniter para esto y tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function rowCountPagos($tabla)
{
    $this->db->select("MONTH(fecha_del_deposito) as mes, SUM(importe) as monto");
    $this->db->from($tabla);
    $this->db->where("fecha_del_deposito = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(fecha_del_deposito) = YEAR(NOW())");
    $this->db->group_by("1");


    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    return $resultados->result();
}
```

Pero no logro que funcione y encuentro el siguiente mensaje

> "Message: Undefined offset: 0"

alguna ayuda con esto? Se los agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Qué error ves? Que ves en los logs? QUé se muestra en pantalla?

Comment: que te devuelve dicha consulta? algun error o datos incorrectos dinos que es lo que ocurre

Comment: @ShadowPaz y Alfabravo El error marcaba "Message: Undefined offset: 0" Pero gracias a DiegoDam Ya esta resuelto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Codeigniter tiene una opción para hacer las consultas directas. Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo quedaría.

```
public function rowCountPagos($tabla){ 
    $query = 'SELECT MONTH(NOW()) AS mes, SUM(importe) as monto 
        FROM '.$tabla.' 
        WHERE MONTH(fecha_del_deposito) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(fecha_del_deposito) = YEAR(NOW()) 
        GROUP BY 1';
    $resultados = $this->db->query($query);
    return $resultados->result();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esa forma de hacer consultar no me la sabia, pero bueno, cada vez adquiero mas conocimiento en este mundo. Gracias hermano :D

Answer (score 4):

Lo que pasa es que **Codeigniter** escapa a los `string` con las comillas, entonces para evitar eso y que considere `MONTH(fecha_del_deposito)` como una función de **SQL** lo que debería hacer es pasarle el segundo parámetro al `$this->db->select()` como `false`, mismo que en el `where` pero en el tercer parámetro. Te quedaría algo así:

```
public function rowCountPagos($tabla)
{
    $this->db->select("MONTH(fecha_del_deposito) as mes, SUM(importe) as monto", false);
    $this->db->from($tabla);
    $this->db->where("fecha_del_deposito", "MONTH(NOW())", false);
    $this->db->where("YEAR(fecha_del_deposito)", "YEAR(NOW())", false);
    $this->db->group_by("1");


    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    return $resultados->result();
}
```

Más [info](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#id1)

Answer (score -2):

```
return $resultados = $this->db->get('tabla')->result();
```

de esta manera traes toda la tabla

Comment: Saludos, es genial que quieras aportar, aunque seria mucho mejor si das una breve explicación de como y porque la solución que propones soluciona el problema que se plantea y sobre todo que cuando adjuntes código lo realices de forma correcta utilizando la herramienta para adjuntar código o presionando **Ctrl+K**, te invito a revisar [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y como no también te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Adelante y gracias por tu aporte ;)