# restar dos campos de diferentes tablas de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, script, consultar

hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar tengo una bases de datos en la cual tengo dos tablas las cuales son:
**almacen**
[image: descripcion1]

**herrramienta**
[image: descripcion2]

Quiero  restar de la tabla almacen del campo cantidad , el numero que se ingrese en el campo cantidadS de tabla herramentas

para lo cual en mi modelo almacen_modelo
creo la función **getUserdatos** en el cual tomo las dos pases de datos

```php
      public function getUserdatos(){  
                $this->db->select("almacen.id ,controldeherramienta.id");
            }
```

Paso el nombre la base de datos almacen

```php
       public function getUserdatos($Nombre)
              {
                  $this->db->select_sum('cantidadS','cantidadS');
                  $this->db->from('herramienta');
//compara el nombre de la herramienta y el nombre de almacen de ser el mismo lo sumo 
                  $this->db->where('herramienta', $Nombre);
                  $row = $this->db->get()->row();
                  //verificamos el retorno
                  if (isset($row)) {
                      //retornamos solamente el valor de cantidad Solicitada
                      return $row->cantidadS;
                  } else {
                      return false;
                  }
              }
```

[image: descripcion3]

En la parte de disponible y nombre  lleno la tabla con los datos que traigo de mi almacén . al ingresar  numero en solicitadas quiero que en mi parte de tabla almacén en campo cantidad se reste la cantidad de herramienta que solicite

[enlace1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/504884/codeigniter-consultas-sql)

[enlace2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/238634/restar-dos-sum-de-tablas-diferentes-en-mysql)

[enlace3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/504884/codeigniter-consultas-sql)

[enlace4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/579936/formulario-con-bot%C3%B3n-de-suma-y-multiplicaci%C3%B3n-no-da-resultado-esperado)

[enlace5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150959/de-consulta-sql-a-consulta-en-codeigniter)

[enlace6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495182/c%C3%B3mo-restar-valores-de-2-consultas-sql-diferentes)

[enlace7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/275314/restar-2-columnas-de-diferentes-tablas-que-comparten-el-mismo-id)

Comment: Lo que tienes ahí son 2 tablas que supongo son de la misma base de datos. Luego dices `quiero restar de la tabla almacen del campo cantidad `, pero en el titulo hablas de restar 2 sumas, luego contra que se tiene que restar lo mismo, contra un campo o contra una suma. Me parece que el problema es fácil, pero tu explicación no la he entendido. Te recomiendo dar un ejemplo de ambas tablas y una salida esperada

Comment: ¿Puedes ser un poco más clara? ¿Por cierto, qué función cumplen los enlaces en tu publicación? Si bien las preguntas pueden estar relacionadas, no me doy cuenta de los motivos. Parece que fueran adornos, hasta tienen el mismo texto.

Comment: exacto tengo en mi base de datos dos tablas almacen y herramientas , en almacen registro la cantidad de herramientas que tengo , en la parte de herramientas la uso para poder pedir herramientas de almacen , traigo los datos de almacen para llenar mi tabla de herramientas quiero que al solicitar una herramienta se descuente de catidad de herramientas que tengo en almacen agrego vista de mis herramientas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás usando un framework como codeigniter, podrías realizar la resta desde el controlador y después aplicar un update a la base de datos

Model_herramienta:

```
public function traerAlmacen($id){
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $resultado = $this->db->get('almacen');
    return $resultado->row();
}

public function traerHerramienta($id){
    $this->db->where('almacen_id',$id);
    $resultado = $this->db->get('almacen');
    return $resultado->row();
}
```

Controlador:

```
$almacen = $this->model_herramienta->traerAlmacen(2);
$herramienta = $this->model_herramienta->traerHerramienta($almacen->id);

$resultado = $almacen->cantidad - $herramienta->cantidadS

$datos = array('cantidad'=>$resultado);
$this->model_herramienta->updateDatos($almacen->id,$datos);
```

Model_herramienta (Aqui aplica el update a la tabla que desee restar):

```
public function updateDatos($id,$datos){
   $this->db->where('id',$id);
   $this->db->update('almacen',$datos);
}
```

No se si el ejemplo que estoy usando te servirá, ubica las tablas como lo necesites. Relaciona la tabla almacen con herramienta. en la tabla almacen puede ir herramienta_id o viceversa

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es restar de tu almacén la cantidad de herramientas solicitadas lo que debes hacer es un `Update`
Supongo que tiene algún botón para registrar esa "Solicitud" de la herramienta. Entonces cuando el usuario da clic en ese botón, se ejecuta un `INSERT INTO` para registrar esa solicitud. Lo que debes hacer es en seguida que se realice ese `INSERT` ejecutas un `UPDATE` con el código de la herramienta que se solicitó, y le restas la cantidad.
Ejemplo de como quedaría tu método:

```
    public function SolicitarHerramienta($id, $nombre, $CantidadSolicitada, $Stockalmacen){
     $cantidadActual = $Stockalmacen - $CantidadSolicitada;
     db.query("INSERT INTO herramientasSolcitadas(id,nombre,cantidad) VALUES ( " + $id + ", " + $nombre + ", " + $CantidadSolicitada + ")");
     db.query("UPDATE almacen WHERE id = " + $id + "SET cantidad = " + $cantidadActual);
}
```

Por lo que veo el usuario puede hacer una lista solicitando varias herramientas, entonces este método de va a repetir para cada elemento de la lista. Con que lo metas dentro de un foreach funciona.
Por lo que noto estás ocupando un framework para hacer las consultas y demás gestiones con MySQL. Desconozco cuál sea entonces no sabría decirte exactamente que poner. Pero con que investigues como hacer un UPDATE con ese framework que ocupas y listo.
Espero haberte ayudado y no revolverte más.

Y perdona si tengo algún error de sintaxis, últimamente no eh manejado PHP estoy más con Java

Comment: estoy usando codeigniter  una una duda  el Stockalmacen que campo de mi base de datos seria

Comment: Stockalmacen seria tu campo Cantidad de la tabla almacen

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada tienes un problema de diseño en la base de datos, no tienes un campo que relacione el id de almacen con la tabla herramientas, esto es importante ya que para hacer el update debe haber un where que relacione esto.
por otro lado veo que los nombres en los campos uno tiene longitud de 100 y en almacen tiene de 50 aparte que colocar el nombre(herramientas) en la tabla herramientas va contra las buenas practicas de diseño.

Me imagino que el campo llamado "castidadS" debería ser "cantidadS" en la tabla herramientas, lo voy a colocar en la respuesta como "cantidadS".

En una respuesta simple en términos de código SQL solo necesitas hacer un update a la tabla `almacen` de la siguiente forma:

Esto con el diseño actual de BD que tienes

```
SQL = "UPDATE almacen
SET cantidad = cantidad - (SELECT cantidadS FROM herramientas WHERE nombre = almacen.nombre)"
```

Ahora crea, utiliza o modificas la función que llamas al momento de introducir la cantidad en ese módulo y ejecutas ese query.

Es relevante tomar en cuenta que si la app es multiusuario es llevar esta operación a otra tabla temporal hasta que se confirme la operación.

Okey ahora te recomiendo este diseño en Base de Datos:

La Tabla "Almacen":

```
"alm_id" sería int(11) Auto incremental
"alm_nombre" sería varchar(100)
"alm_cantidad" sería int(11)
```

La Tabla "Herramientas":

```
"herr_id" sería int(11) Auto incremental
"herr_cantidad" sería int(11)
"alm_id" sería int(11) Clave Foránea con relación a la tabla Almacén en el campo Alm_id
```

Entonces allí tienes un buen diseño de Base de datos que te simplificaría mucho la consulta para saber, el nombre de la herramienta, la disponibilidad en almacen, etc.

Si encuentras términos aquí que no conoces te recomiendo que fortalezcas el conocimiento en MySQL sobre todo en diseño de bases de datos, manejos de claves foráneas y uniones (joins) etc.

Aquí podrías comenzar: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/